# Rendered image in eevee is not displaying shadows

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am not sure where to look.

Both renderings are done with the exact same operating system environment settings yet one of them is not displaying shadows. What is the difference here and how do I fix it?

I have tried shutting down and restarting the computer numerous times with no changes to either file.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: so on the first file you can get shadows but if you create a new one you can't anymore?

Comment: Yes, for the most part, I am able to get a new render with any object I create out of the first file but not with any other files. I have simply decided to make the first file as my starter template for now.

Answer (score -1):

EEVEE fakes pretty much everything in the scene when rendering. This includes Ambient Occlusion (which creates more realistic shading in EEVEE), reflections, refractions, etc. If you want a better result in EEVEE, I would recommend you use an [HDRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_imaging) map, and enable the checkbox for "Ambient Occlusion" in the render properties panel.

You can download high quality HDRs and HDRIs for free [here](https://hdrihaven.com/).

More about Ambient Occlusion (AO) in the Blender Manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/ambient_occlusion.html).

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted with no clear explanation? This has seemed to happen to multiple of my answers frequently with no reason.